# Rigify rig can't move my mesh only rotate 2.79a

Tags: rigify

For some reason I am unable to move certain parts of my mesh with the rig.

This is the default pose and it appears as everything is good.
[image: Default Pose]

However, when I try to move the arms or legs I am unable to do so. Example below:
[image]

I can still use the ball joints to rotate along the arms and move the fingers, head, torso like so though:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rig has two way of moving arms and legs: IK and FK; you can choose the behaviour using the IK/FK slider on the N properties panel.

In your case Ik is selected and you are trying to move the arm with the FK controllers, which are disabled.

[image]